# Filling NaN in each row with the mean of existing values except its NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I am a beginner in the basics of data analysis and have a problem that I could not solve it with my current knowledge and searching on various sites, especially the StackOverflow site.
I have a sample data frame like the one below and I need to fill NaN with a specific condition:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['row 1', 1, 2, 3, 4], ['row 2', 5, nan, 7, 8], ['row 3', nan, nan, 11, 12]], index=['A', 'B', 'C'], columns=['rows', '1st', '2nd', '3th', '4th'])
df
```

| rows | 1st | 2nd | 3rd | 4th |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1.0 | 2.0 | 3 | 4 |
| B | 5.0 | NaN *>> fill with (5.0+7+8) / 3 = 6.66...* | 7 | 8 |
| C | NaN *>> fill with (11+12) / 2 = 11.5* | NaN *>> fill with (11+12) / 2 = 11.5* | 11 | 12 |

In each row that contains NaN, I have some numbers. To fill NaN I have to calculate their values with this formula:
*(sum of existing numbers in the row) / (number of existing numbers in the row)*.
For example in row 'B', the NaN should fill with the shown formula.
Thank you in advance for any advice.

I tried this code in notebook but my data frame didn't changed:

```
df.fillna((df[df.isna() == False].sum(axis=1)) / (4 - df.isna().sum(axis=1)), inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compute the mean along the column axis then fill nan values:

```
mean = df.mean(axis=1, numeric_only=True)
out = df.T.fillna(mean).T
```

Output:

```
>>> out
    rows   1st       2nd 3th 4th
A  row 1   1.0       2.0   3   4
B  row 2   5.0  6.666667   7   8
C  row 3  11.5      11.5  11  12

>>> mean
A     2.500000
B     6.666667
C    11.500000
dtype: float64
```

**Update**: a shortest solution inspired by @anoushiravan-r:

```
>>> df.mask(df.isna(), df.mean(axis=1, numeric_only=True), axis=0)
    rows   1st        2nd  3th  4th
A  row 1   1.0   2.000000    3    4
B  row 2   5.0   6.666667    7    8
C  row 3  11.5  11.500000   11   12
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also try the following solution:

```
import pandas as pd

df.where(~ df.isna(), df.iloc[:, 1:].mean(axis=1), axis=0)

    rows   1st        2nd  3th  4th
A  row 1   1.0   2.000000    3    4
B  row 2   5.0   6.666667    7    8
C  row 3  11.5  11.500000   11   12
```

Or you could also try thanks to a very good suggestion by @Corralien:

```
df.where(~ df.isna(), df.mean(axis=1, numeric_only=True), axis=0)
```

Comment: You can use `df.mask` instead of `df.where`: `df.mask(df.isna(), df.iloc[:, 1:].mean(axis=1), axis=0)`

Comment: Yes of course, that's my favorite of the two. Thought I would use `df.where` this time. But you are right. By the way I have just come to know `select_dtypes` thanks to your answer. It seems like a very useful method. Coming from R I never knew we could apply a function on columns in python based on column type. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: You can also avoid the `.iloc` by using `numeric_only=True` as parameter of `mean`

Comment: Yes just added the second solution as well :)

Comment: I've learned new things from your solution and @Corralien's. Solutions helped me to solve the problem. Thanks for your time.